# How to increment the Range of a For Each loop - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a loop where I am trying to increment which cells a formula gets posted in. I confirmed my loop already works, I just don't quite know how to limit it to post the formula every increment, instead of every cell.

Maybe I shouldn't be using a For Each Loop here?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert_Formula_Sum()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, c As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rcell As Range
    Dim LI As Worksheet
    Set LI = Sheets("Lumber Inventory")
    
    'Set lower range of dataset
    LastRow = LI.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Set range of For Each loop
    Set rng = Range("D8:D" And LastRow)
    
    i = 3
    c = 3
    
    For Each rcell In rng
        rcell.Formula = "=SUM(D" & i & ":D" & c & ")"
        i = i + 7
        c = c + 7
        rcell = rcell + 7
    Next rcell

End Sub
```

I just don't quite know how I would go about incrementing the Range. You can see my juevenile attempt with:

```
rcell = rcell + 7
```

But of course this gives a datatype mismatch, as this is dimmed as a Range and not an integer.

Comment: Use a standard `For` loop : `For x = 8 to LastRow Step 7`  Then you would do `Range("D" & x).Formula = "=SUM(D" & i & ":D" & c & ")"`

Comment: Also, `Set rng = Range("D8:D" & LastRow)`

Comment: As a side note, the way to select a cell offset from another cell is with `.Offset()`. for example, instead of `rcell = rcell + 7`, you would use `Set rcell = rcell.Offset(7,0)`. This still wouldn't work inside your `For Each` Loop, but it's helpful to know.

Comment: @braX Would I need to set the range inside of the Loop? Otherwise I don't quite see how setting a range is necessary since the only thing interacting with it was the `For Each rcell in rng` portion.

Comment: The loop is based on the range, so you do not want to put it in the loop. That wouldn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula seems to sum 1 single cell, if that's incorrect you'll need to adjust the +- on `I` Start, Step, I-3, I-3.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert_Formula_Sum()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim LI As Worksheet
    
    Set LI = Sheets("Lumber Inventory")
    
    With LI
        
        ' Find Last Row#
        LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For I = 8 To LastRow Step 7
            .Range("D" & I).Formula = _
                "=SUM(D" & I - 3 & ":D" & I - 3 & ")"
        Next I
        
    End With

End Sub
```

This is current output:
[image]

But if you change the formula line to:
`... = "=SUM(D" & I - 6 & ":D" & I - 1 & ")"`
Then output is:
[image]

Comment: Oops, It definitely was supposed to be as you changed the formula to, I must've been going too quickly and set variables to the same integer.